# UItableView cell first row selection not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a `UITableView` in which I set background colour for first row is to grey. By this code

```
        // showing the selection in UITableViewCell

        if indexPath.row == 0
        {
           cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 189 / 255, green: 189 / 255, blue: 189 / 255, alpha: 0.55)
        }
```

Now I put code in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` to change the colour to white like this.

```
var cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0))

// hiding the seleciton in UITableViewCell

if indexPath.row == 0
{
   cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```

When table loads, it shows a grey background in the first row, Which indicates that first row is selected and values are shown in `DetailViewController`. If I click in other rows the zeroth row colour changes to white and other rows gets colour grey by the `UITableSelectionStyleGrey`.

After the table loading, if scroll down a long. And if I select in a row then suddenly it app crashes and shows `Fatal-Error : Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping a nil value`. I have no idea why this happens.. I tried by putting only these simple codes in the dataSource and delegate methods,Still getting the same error when I scroll down and select a row.

Any suggestions.? Thanks in advance.

Complete code given below.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as WordsCustomTableViewCell

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Gray

    // showing the selection in UITableViewCell

    if indexPath.row == 0
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 189 / 255, green: 189 / 255, blue: 189 / 255, alpha: 0.55)
    }

    return cell
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDelegate Methods

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{

    var cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0))

   // hiding the selection in UITableViewCell

    if indexPath.row == 0
    {
       cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()    
    }

}
```

Comment: If you are doing this so that row 0 appears to be selected, I would suggest that, instead of the above logic, you just put some code into `viewDidLoad` to select the first row (using the `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` function).

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep selection data in separate structure (I recommend NSMutableSet for that) and add indexPaths of row that get's selected.

Later in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you need to check if indexPath is inside NSMutableSet and based on that configure a cell backgroundColor. You will be forced to reload a table row at index path after it's selected.

Reason for behaviour you have problem with is that `UITableViewCell` is reused across different indexPaths and it's is prepared to reuse (resets selection).

Comment: Also you have any idea about why its crashing if i scroll down to the end and select last or second last row .??

Comment: You should really read documentation about UITableView first before coding or go through some tutorials. You have such mistakes like this: var cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)) in didSelectRowAtIndexPath which doesn't make any sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

try this it may help you if i understand your question correctly..

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
        {
    //        var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableObj.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell
    //        cell.textLabel?.text="I am learning swift Day \(indexPath.row)"

             var cell:customTableViewCell = self.tableObj.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell") as customTableViewCell
            cell.nameLbl.text=nameList[indexPath.row]
            cell.imageView?.image=imgListArray[indexPath.row] as? UIImage

            if indexPath.row == 0
            {
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 189 / 255, green: 189 / 255, blue: 189 / 255, alpha: 0.55)
            }
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Gray


            return cell
        }
        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
        {

            var cell = self.tableObj.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0))

            // hiding the selection in UITableViewCell

            if indexPath.row != 0
            {
                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            }
        }
```

Comment: This alone will not solve problem, It will show background colour for every reused cell in row 1